# Qt UI testing: How to simulate a click on a QMenuBar item using QTest?

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qtestlib

I am trying to simulate a mouse click on a QMenu item from a QMenuBar, for example clicking on "Save As" QAction using the QTestLib framework.

I am triyng this under Windows XP 32 bit and Qt 5.0.2.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What would that achieve?  Just call `QAction::trigger()`.

Comment: I am trying to make an automated test app for a UI.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do as well. I think the complication here is that QMenu does not create a widget for each QAction: the menu items are pretty much just drawn directly onto the menu's rectangle.

Answer (score 8):

Probably this question is not relevant for question owner, but I suppose it could be helpful for others.

Unlike `QToolBar`, `QMenu` doesn't have method `widgetForAction`. I found a simple workaround for this case. Try popup menu with `QTest::mouseClick` if nothing happens try to use `QTest::keyClick(..., first_char_in_menu_tite, Qt::AltModifier)`. To simulate action execution you can navigate with `Qt::Key_Down` to action until you reach it and then press `Qt::Key_Enter`. I suppose following code can help you to understand

```
QMenu *menu = getMenu(mainWindow, menuName);
if (menu != nullptr) {
    QTest::keyClick(mainWindow, menu->title().at(1).toLatin1(), Qt::AltModifier);
}


QList<QAction *> actions = menu->actions();
foreach (QAction *action, actions) {
    if (action->objectName() == actionName) {
        QTest::keyClick(menu, Qt::Key_Enter);
        break;
    }
    QTest::qWait(1000);
    QTest::keyClick(menu, Qt::Key_Down);
}
```

Comment: I made a similar example but for QComboBox here.  Thanks for posting the QMenu one! https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/cbd8eaa0e565d0b82dbfb5c7fdc61c8d

Answer (score -2):

You should use the [QTest::mouseClick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html#mouseClick) function.  It will simulate the click on any QWidget.  I have found that trying to click on a QMenu that causes a blocking call will not work with a unit test.

Comment: Not a good answer because the issue is being able to simulate a click specifically on one element, "Save As...", of a menu. Even if you can simulate a click on the "File" menu button, then the menu is displayed, somewhere in the menu rectangle is the "Save As..." part but how do you simulate a click on that? There is no child widget to access (or is there?).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Because the question ask for a mouseClick on a QAction. But QAction does not inherits from QWidget. Thus this solution is totally false.